# Bilinear form and signature

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I have a bilinear form such that the associate matrix is

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix} 0&0&k\\ 0&k&0\\ k&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

For which $k$ the quadratic for has signature $(1,2)$?

Comment: $F$ is definited like $F: xz′+yy′+zx′$

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need for Sylvester's Law of Inertia

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & k \\ 
0 & k & 0 \\ 
k & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
k & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 k& 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ k }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
k & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2k & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ k }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & k \\ 
0 & k & 0 \\ 
k & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

======================================================

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: i dont understand